# Firebase cloud function TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions

I use firebase real time database and firebase cloud I tried the if users pushid below have expoToken,I wrote the message the pushnotification/{id} and send the message with expoToken,(I write react native with expo I try the send a push notification)that is my use case anyway just my problem is I run this function and give me an TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined error, how can I fix this

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var fetch = require('node-fetch');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendPushNotification = functions.database
  .ref('pushnotification/{id}')
  .onCreate(event => {
    const root = event.data.ref.root;

    var messages = [];
    return root
      .child('/users')
      .once('value')
      .then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
          var expoToken = childSnapshot.val().expoToken;
          if (expoToken) {
            messages.push({
              to: expoToken,
              body: 'New node Added'
            });
          }
        });
        return Promise.all(messages);
      })
      .then(() => {
        fetch('https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringfy(messages)
        });
      });
  });
```

Comment: Are you following an old tutorial?  It's using a very old version of the Cloud Functions for Firebase API, but you're building against a newer version.